# Java: fail to get the absolute path of a file

Tags: java

Below is my project like:

```
projectName
    -package
      - Util.java
      - Test.json
```

In Util.java, I need to read the content from Test.json file and parse it.
Thus I use:

```
File currentfile = new File("");//get the current path
String absJsonPath  = currentfile.getAbsolutePath() + "/Test.json";
```

While it did not work when I use a main method to test it. The thing is that the /src/package is lost in the obtained file path and **I just got the path of the project**.

And, when I deploy the project to weblogic server, I got another new error, the obtained current path is like:

```
.../DefaultDomain/.
```

I just want the file path in the file system, which is not related to the server.

What can I do for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put your file in resources folder and get it as following:

```
//Get file from resources folder
  ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Test.json").getFile());
```

To read the content you can use following:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");

try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        result.append(line).append("\n");
    }

    scanner.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's CanonicalPath() not Absolute. Check this out, let me know if it any helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get current path

> String currentPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

Comment: I tried it but still the same issue: the package is lost, I can only get the path of the project but not the current file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file in a specific package. You can use

```
File jsonFile = new File(getClass().getResource("/Test.json").getFile());
```